# Conditions on a closed subset $F$ of a Banach space $E$ such that the projection into $F$ exists for any $a\in E$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, projection

Let $(E, | \cdot|)$ be a Banach space and $F$ a closed subset of $E$. Fix $a \in E$. In general, there does not necessarily exist $b \in F$ such that
$$
|b-a| = \inf_{x\in F}|x-a|.
$$

Are there some conditions on the set $F$ to guarantee that such projection exists for every $a\in E$?

---

**Update:** I have recently solved [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4388468/can-breziss-ex-3-9-be-generalized-to-arbitrary-subset-m-of-e/4388469) question. It suggests that in case of the dual space $E'$, if $M \subseteq E'$ is closed in the weak$^\star$ topology $\sigma(E', E)$, then the projection into $M$ exists for any $f\in E'$.

Comment: If $F$ is compact then $b$ exists necessarily.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Fix $a\in E$, then the map $x \mapsto |x-a|$ is continuous and thus attains both minimum and maximum on the compact set $F$. Compactness is usually a strong condition. Are there weaker ones?

Comment: There is no general weaker condition that I can think of. If $E$ is finite dimensional then any closed set will do.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: weak compactness should work as well, as the norm is weakly lower semicontinuous

Comment: Such sets that admit  best approximations are often called proximinal. It can be shown that if $E$ is reflexive, and $F$ is closed and convex then $F$ is proximinal. Furthermore, if $E$ is reflexive and strictly convex, then there exists exactly one best approximation. In that case, $F$ is said to be Chebyshev, and the (nonlinear) map that sends each $x \in E$ to its best approximation in $F$ is called the metric projection of $F$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such sets that admit best approximations are often called proximinal. It can be shown that if $E$ is reflexive, and $F$ is closed and convex then $F$ is proximinal. (The converse is also true; namely, if every closed and convex subset of $E$ is proximinal then $E$ is reflexive). Furthermore, if $E$ is reflexive and strictly convex, then there exists exactly one best approximation. In that case, $F$ is said to be Chebyshev. (In fact, $E$ is strictly convex and reflexive iff each of its  closed and convex subsets is Chebyshev). The
(nonlinear) map that sends each $x \in E$ to its best approximation in $F$ is called the metric projection of $F$.